# How to speed up the use of httr with multiple GET queries?

Tags: r, api, get, httr

### My issue

I have a large dataset (> 40 000 rows) and I want to use an API to get a code for each row by sending queries with 2 arguments.

Everything works, but it is quite slow (~1.5 second per row) and I get an error message when reaching row 3401 :

```
Error in curl::curl_fetch_memory(url, handle = handle) : 
  Timeout was reached: Operation timed out after 10969 milliseconds with 0 out of 0 bytes received
```

### My reproducible code

```
library(tidyverse)
library(jsonlite)
library(httr)

# example dataset ---------------------------------------------------------

data_example = tibble(ADRESSE = c("20 Rue de la Tour d'Auvergne",
                                  "21 Rue Lucien Sampaix",
                                  "1 Parvis Notre-Dame"),
                      CP = c("75009",
                             "75010",
                             "75004"))

# function ----------------------------------------------------------------

get_my_iris = function(adresse , cp ) {
  print(Sys.time())
  tt = httr::VERB(
    verb = "GET", url = "https://pyris.datajazz.io/api/search/",
    httr::add_headers(accept = "application/json"),
    query = list(
      geojson = "false",
      q = adresse, postcode = cp
    )
  )

  text = content(tt,as="text",encoding = "UTF-8")
  df = fromJSON(text, flatten = TRUE) %>% data.frame()
  if(length(df) > 0){
    return(as.character(df$complete_code))
  } else { 
    return("NO CODE")
  }
}

# purrr -------------------------------------------------------------------

map2_chr(data_example$ADRESSE,data_example$CP, ~get_my_iris(adresse = .x, cp =.y))
```

Is there a way to speed up this task ?